# How plausible is it running code on a Raspberry Pi 24/7

Tags: python, windows, raspberry-pi

How useful would it be running code from the ide Visual studio code 24/7 on a Raspberry pi? I'm trying to have this project send texts at certain times a day and running it on my computer all day seems like a bad idea I've read. So how plausible would it be to get a raspberry pi and run this code on it all day?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the 24/7 isn't a problem.  The nice thing about Rasberry PI they all run under 10 watts.  The problem will be running Visual Studio.  I don't think you can bring VStudio up on a RPI; it is way too big.  Running the application itself, shouldn't be an issue though, depending on size and complexity of course.  Create and debug the application someplace else, then running the python on RPI should not be an issue.

Comment: So I should export my visual studio project into a exc then send it over to my raspberry pi so it could run it like that? After the debugging of course.

Comment: @JahmiaGallimore Precisely

Comment: Thanks, @RayanHatout and FrankMerrow for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Very plausible, but running code at certain times of the day seems to be better suited for something called a `cronjob`, which your Pi will support.

https://www.ostechnix.com/a-beginners-guide-to-cron-jobs/